# Can someone explain why "void func_dec(void (*)(int) funcptr);" is illegal

Tags: c, function-pointers, function-declaration

When declaring a functions which takes function pointer as argument as mentioned  below the compiler throws error.

```
 void func_dec(int x, void(*)() funcptr);
```

Whereas it accepts below declaration,

```
 void func_dec(int x, void(*funcptr)());
```

Why the compiler could not recognize the former declaration though it looks logical.

Comment: Because that's not the syntax specified in the grammar.

Comment: While declaring a function in C, it is highly recommended that you should know what exactly is the syntax of working. If you do not have an idea then you should read about it. I do not understand what you are trying to achieve, and why you require such a complex declaration?

Comment: You may find http://cdecl.org/  helpful in constructing complicated C types.

Comment: @JafferWilson it's not that complex, it's a function which takes an int and a function pointer as arguments, quite often used for registering callbacks and similar

Comment: I can think of many declarations which look logical but the compiler would not recognize.

Comment: I highly recommend using `typedef` to simplify function pointer usage. Define `typedef void FuncType();` and use as `void func_dec(int x, FuncType * funcptr);`

Comment: I can understand that grammar specified is not logical in this case. But if something defy's logic there must be or may be a reason.

Comment: Upvoted the question: this type of declaration is counter-intuitive, even if there is a reason for that. One must use the available syntax, and yet be free to criticize it.

Answer (score 2):

It is illegal because the formal definition in the language standard says so. As for the reason why it is that way, and it really may seem obscure, here it is:

From [The New C Standard: An Economic and Cultural Commentary (v 1.2 from June 24, 2009, section 6.7 Declarations)](http://www.knosof.co.uk/cbook/cbook.html):

> The intent of this syntax is for an identifier’s declarator to have
>   the same visual appearance as an instance of that identifier in an
>   expression. For instance, in:
>
> int x[3], *y, z(void);
>
> char (*f(int))[];
>
> the identifier x might appear in the source as an indexed
>   array, y as a dereferenced pointer, and z as a function call. An
>   example of an expression using the result of a call to f is
>   (*f(42))[1].

And the same from [The Development of the C Language by Dennis M. Ritchie](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html):

> Thus,
>
> int i, *pi, **ppi;
>
> declare an integer, a pointer to an integer, a
>   pointer to a pointer to an integer. The syntax of these declarations
>   reflects the observation that i, *pi, and **ppi all yield an int type
>   when used in an expression. Similarly,
>
> int f(), *f(), (*f)();
>
> declare
>   a function returning an integer, a function returning a pointer to an
>   integer, a pointer to a function returning an integer;
>
> int *api[10], (*pai)[10];
>
> declare an array of pointers to integers, and a pointer to
>   an array of integers. In all these cases the declaration of a variable
>   resembles its usage in an expression whose type is the one named at
>   the head of the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This is because,

```
 void(*)() funcptr
```

is in invalid syntax on it's own.

Just supply the *type* while writing the function declaration,

```
void func_dec(int , void(*) ());
```

it should be enough. Otherwise, if you want to specify the variable name also, write

```
 void func_dec(int x, void(*funcptr) ());
```

Answer (score 1):

The function parameter name should go in the same place as the function name goes when you declare a function.

Function declaration:

```
void func();  // correct syntax
void() func;  // incorrrect syntax
```

Function pointer declaration:

```
void (*func_ptr)();  // correct syntax
void (*)() func_ptr; // incorrect syntax
```

Declaring a function pointer becomes easier if you use the following trick:

Take the function declaration. Replace the function name with `(*pointerName)`, or `(*)` if you want an unnamed version.

Example:

```
 int func1(char* parm1);        // function
 int (*func1_ptr)(char* parm1); // function pointer

 // function taking a function pointer as parameter:
 void foo(int (*func1_ptr)(char*));
 // The same declaration with an unnamed parameter:
 void foo(int (*)(char*));
```

Comment: @FabioTurati Thanks. I read your version using the "right-left" rule and you are correct. I read my version and got... lost. I removed it from my answer.